# Why does $q.when not resolve when wrapping a third-party promise when using ngMock?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, promise, angular-promise

Given the following service:

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .service('promisey', function ($q) {
    this.cakey = function () {
      return $q.when('brownie')
    }
    this.fruity = function () {
      return $q.when(Promise.resolve('apple'))
    }
  })
```

… and the following test:

```
var self = this

describe('when', function () {
  var promisey
  var $rootScope

  beforeEach(module('app'))
  beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_, _promisey_) {
    promisey = _promisey_
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_
  }))

  it('should give cakes', function (done) {
    promisey.cakey()
      .then(function (cake) {
        expect(cake).toBe('brownie')
      })
      .catch(self.fail.bind())
      .finally(done)
    $rootScope.$apply()
  })

  it('should give fruit', function (done) {
    promisey.fruity()
      .then(function (cake) {
        // XXX: does not resolve
        expect(cake).toBe('apple')
      })
      .catch(self.fail.bind())
      .finally(done)
    $rootScope.$apply()
  })
})
```

… when `ngMock` is sourced, `promisey.fruity()` will never resolve. If I do not source `ngMock` (and handle `angular.injector` myself), the test will resolve as expected. Why is that?

A reduced test case of this question can be found at [tlvince/q-when-reduced-test-case](https://github.com/tlvince/q-when-reduced-test-case).

Comment: Where tests are executed? In the browser that supports `Promise`?

Comment: They're ran via PhantomJS with a polyfilled `Promise` via lie (http://git.io/vZxcs).

Answer (score 3):

This is because native promises use a different scheduler than Angular. Angular schedules promises via `evalAsync` on its async queue. Different promise libraries may schedule promises differently - in your use case of native promises it schedules via something called "the microtask queue".

When you call `$rootScope.$apply` it "flushes the evalAsync queue" since a digest cycle is run, this simulates "async" and lets you test promises.

You can't "cheat" timers this way with native promises, so you have to write a test that's actually asynchronous.

You can not use ngMock and use Mocha's promise syntax:

```
  it('should give fruit', function () { // no done
    return promisey.fruity() // see return here
      .then(function (cake) {
        expect(cake).toBe('apple')
      });
      // no digest, no `done`
  });
```

I think it looks a lot nicer anyway :)

Comment: Your description of the differing schedulers makes sense. However, your example test will not work as expected; the assertion will always pass. For example, see http://git.io/vZxGG, which is using Jasmine 2.x (with async support).

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying here really, you used another test framework and are complaining that a different framework doesn't behave the same (you didn't specify Jasmine in the question). You can use Jasmine-As-Promised if you want to return promises from Jasmine.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't familiar with Mocha's built-in promise support and otherwise expected it to behave the same as Jasmine. However, even with Mocha, the test does not pass (it times out). I also tried two other async testing variants, to no avail. See: http://git.io/vZx0O.

Comment: Look at my code above, remove the `done` and `return` the promise. Promises are pretty simple - they work by using the `return` value, whenever you had code that takes a callback - it `returns` a promise now.

Comment: I copied your code almost verbatim (with a slight tweak for expect.js): https://github.com/tlvince/q-when-reduced-test-case/blob/db509dd7f127340d0ca7c76e2a5cbeb82e867776/test/when.spec.js#L24-L29